# EF Core - composite primary key removes one index

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have this entity:

```
[Table("order")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    [Column("student_id")]
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employer")]
    [Column("employer_id")]
    public Guid EmployerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    [Column("customer_id")]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Employer { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And I see next snapshot of `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("DataInterface.Models.Order", b =>
{
    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnName("id");

    b.Property<string>("Description")
        .HasColumnName("description")
        .HasMaxLength(128);

    b.Property<Guid>("StudentId")
        .HasColumnName("student_id");

    b.Property<Guid>("EmployerId")
        .HasColumnName("employer_id");

    b.Property<Guid>("CustomerId")
        .HasColumnName("customer_id");

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.HasIndex("StudentId");

    b.HasIndex("EmployerId");

    b.HasIndex("CustomerId");

    b.ToTable("order");
});
```

How can you see - all fine. But I need to create a composite key and delete primary key. So, let's do it. My new code of the entity (without `Id` primary key):

```
[Table("order")]
public class Order
{
    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    [Column("student_id")]
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employer")]
    [Column("employer_id")]
    public Guid EmployerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    [Column("customer_id")]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Employer { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I add new behavior to the `OnModelCreating` method of my context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.StudentId, x.EmployerId, x.CustomerId });
}
```

When I add new migration then I see that the index of `StudentId` was deleted. And I don't understand why? My new snapshot of `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("DataInterface.Models.Order", b =>
{
    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnName("id");

    b.Property<string>("Description")
        .HasColumnName("description")
        .HasMaxLength(128);

    b.Property<Guid>("StudentId")
        .HasColumnName("student_id");

    b.Property<Guid>("EmployerId")
        .HasColumnName("employer_id");

    b.Property<Guid>("CustomerId")
        .HasColumnName("customer_id");

    b.HasKey("StudentId", "EmployerId", "CustomerId");

    b.HasIndex("EmployerId");

    b.HasIndex("CustomerId");

    b.ToTable("order");
});
```

Why one of three indexes was deleted? Why `b.HasIndex("StudentId");` line was deleted? What's wrong?

Note: I don't see this problem with a composite key from two fields in another tables.

Comment: The primary key index is also an index on StudentID, so the additional index is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary key is enforced by an index.

`StudentId` is the first column in that index.

It doesn't need another index defined on it (such an index would almost certainly be pointless too since it's likely that the PK index is the clustered index for the table and non-clustered indexes contain the PK columns at their leaves)

Comment: EF always creates the index on its PK columns as the clustered one (by default). It even still is quite a hassle to make another index to be clustered.

Answer (score 2):

An additional index on `StudentId` would be redundant. Since this is the first column in your primary key, a lookup on `StudentId` can simply use its index. Similarly a lookup on `StudentId`+`EmployerId` can do the same.

Anecdotally, this used to *not* be the case with EF Core, and two indexes were created. The fact that the index is being removed now means that this behavior has been fixed/optimized.